# Adding custom user ID to Vanity's "track!" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vanity

There's a Vanity metric that is tracked by a cronjob, long after the user has left the website.

How should I pass the user ID to the "track!" method to ensure that the conversion is handled properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `identity` option to the `track!` method, [as the documentation shows](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/vanity/Vanity/Helpers:track!):

```
track!(:click, :identity => 'user_id')
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I pass the identity option and the value one?  

My code used to be:  
  
    track! :metric, @variable.value.to_i  
  
The documentation doesn't make it clear.

Comment: The documentation lists the example of passing the `values` option to the hash, e.g. : `track!(:click, identity: 'user_id', values: [@variable.value.to_i])`